# Bootstrap - getting the id of a multiselect element in a table

Tags: multi-select

I am new to bootstrap and i am trying to use the multiselect element in a table to act as a filter selector.

I can get the values chosen by using the onchange event, but how can I get the ID of the field the select element is in? I have tried different variations and combinations of $this, event and .id.

I really need to know what field this select is in or else I can't use it.

(The commented out code on the var fieldId line are some of the options I have tried)

TIA

```html
    // Multi select
    $('.chosen-select').multiselect({
 buttonWidth: '150px',
 includeSelectAllOption: true,
 enableFiltering: true,
 onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
  var fieldId = $(option.target)[0]; //=$(this).attr("id"); option.target.id ; $(option).id; $(select).id;
  console.log('ID = ' + fieldId +' or '+ this.id + ' Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your onChange event:

```js
var selectID = $(option).parent().attr('id');
```

Here's a full example:

```js
$('#multiSelect1').multiselect({
  onChange: function(option, checked) {
    var selectID = $(option).parent().attr('id');
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="multiSelect1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For events without params, for example: **onSelectAll**, you might use this way

```
var selectId = $(this.$select).attr('id');
```